# How to configure a custom 400 response with thin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I am using thin as my web server in rails application. While trying to hit a url [http://localhost:3000/search/%](http://localhost:3000/search/%25) **thin** is throwing

```
 Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
```

How to write custom 400 response handler with **thin**?

Comment: something will help you https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update nginx configuration file as below and create 400.html file in public folder.

```
server { listen 80;

root /public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!

error_page 400 /400.html;
location = /400.html {
internal;
}

location / {
return 400;
}

}
```